# Change Sender Name

Tags: node.js, gmail, sendgrid

If I get an email to myself using Sendgrid which was triggered by a user who submitted a form in my website, the email which I received has a sender's name which is specified as "me" because ultimately I am both the sender and the receiver in this case, even though I have specified that the sender's name as user's lastName but it is being overwritten as "me" again, i want the sender's name to be the user's last name, how should i proceed with this case if I am using node.js as my server-side scripting?

```
  const clientOptions = {
    to: client,
    from: {
      name: data.lastName, // Optionally, set the sender's name
      email: client, // Set the sender's email address
    },
    reply_to: {
      email: data.email,
    },
    subject: `New Response from ${data.lastName}`,
  };
```